Prove $(A')' \subset A'$ in general topological spaces
I'm trying to prove the set of accumulation points is closed in general topological spaces,
all proofs I've found are for metric spaces, I know arguments are similar but I haven't been able to complete the proof.
Here's what I've done:
Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, $A \subset X$ and let $A'$ be the set of accumulation points of $A$
If $ x \in (A')'$, then $\forall U \in \tau$ such that $x \in U$, $U \cap (A'-\{x\}) \neq \oslash$,
Then there exists $y \in U \cap (A'-\{x\})$, which in turn is in $A'$, so again we have that
$\forall V \in \tau$ such that $y \in V$, $V \cap (A-\{y\}) \neq \oslash$.
So there is some $z \in V \cap (A-\{y\})$.
Now since $U$ is a neighborhood of $y$,
$U \cap (A-\{y\}) \neq \oslash$.
How can I conclude that $U \cap (A-\{x\}) \neq \oslash$ or $V \cap (A-\{x\}) \neq \oslash$?

I think this post answers your question.
